# Shifting an array after removing a value (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I made a program that makes an array of random ints and doubles in size if the user tries to add an int. Example: 1|2|3|4  if they were to add another int it would look like 1|2|3|4|5|0|0|0. I have made a method to add an int which works but now I am trying to make methods that remove one of a certain int and another that removes all of a certain int. for example removeInt(3) would give me 1|2|0|4|5|0|0|0. I have the first part working so that it shifts the zero to the end like this 1|2|4|5|0|0|0|0 but cannot get it to work for more than one of the same value. Any suggestions?

```
    // ****************************************************************
// IntegerList.java
//
// Define an IntegerList class with methods to create & fill
// a list of integers.
//
// ****************************************************************

public class IntegerList
{
    int[] list; //values in the list
//-------------------------------------------------------
//create a list of the given size
//-------------------------------------------------------
    public IntegerList(int size) 

    {
        list = new int[size];
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------
//fill array with integers between 1 and 100, inclusive
//-------------------------------------------------------
    public void randomize()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            list[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    }
//-------------------------------------------==----------
//print array elements with indices
//-------------------------------------------------------
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ":\t" + list[i]);
    }
    public void addElement(int newVal){
        boolean full = true;
        System.out.println(list.length);
        int position = 0;
        int place;
        while(position < list.length){
            System.out.println("HERE");
                if(list[position]==0){
                    System.out.println("here");
                    full = false;
                    place = position;
                    System.out.println(place);
                }
                position = position+1;
            }
        if(full == true){
            list = increaseSize(list);
            System.out.println("L"+list.length);
            full = false;
            }

        for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
            if(list[i]==0){
                if(i<position){
                    position = i;
            System.out.println(list.length);
                }
            }
        }
        list[position] = newVal;
    }
    public void removeFirst(int newVal){
        int position = 0;
        boolean removed = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<list.length;i++){
            if(list[i] == newVal){
                list[i]=0;
                position = i;
                removed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(removed==true){
            for(int i = position;i<list.length;i++){
                if(i!=list.length-1){
                    list[i]=list[i+1];
                }
            }
            list[list.length-1]= 0;
        }
    }
    public void removeAll(int newVal){
        int position = 0;
        boolean removed = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<list.length;i++){
            if(list[i] == newVal){
                list[i]=0;
                position = i;
                removed = true;
            }
        }
        if(removed==true){
            for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
                if(i!=list.length-1 && list[i+1]==newVal){
                    list[i]=0;
                }
                if(list[i]==newVal){
                    list[i]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    public static int[] increaseSize(int[] x){
        int newLength = x.length *2;
        int[] newx = new int[newLength];
        for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
            newx[i] = x[i];
        }
        return newx;
    }
    public static int[] halfSize(int[] x){
        int[] newx = new int[x.length / 2];
        for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
            newx[i] = x[i];
        }
        return newx;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the 'removeFirst' methods works, can't you just keep on calling it for the 'removeAll' method? Perhaps removeFirst returns a boolean for whether it found an element to remove or not, so when it returns false you know you're done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an easier way to implement your `removeAll` method. Move 2 (rather than 1) indices through your array constantly shifting the values over the items you are removing;

```
int dest = 0;
int source = 0;
while (source < array.length) {
    if (array[dest] != valueToRemove)
        dest++;
    array[dest] = array[source++];
}
while (dest < array.length) {
    array[dest++] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code and found out that the problem is in this piece, under removeAll()...

```
if(removed){
        for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
            if(i!=list.length-1 && list[i+1]==newVal){
                list[i]=0;
            }
            if(list[i]==newVal){
                list[i]=0;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you comment out and try once, you will see the removeAll() is working and your desired number is replaced with 0s. Now why you don't simply check your numbers and shift(sorting), if they are greater than 0 to the left?